# Are the arguments of a C program guaranteed to be '\0'-terminated?

Tags: c, security, posix, c11, execve

About the arguments of `main()`, the 2011 C standard says (5.1.2.2.1:2):

> If the value of argc is greater than zero, the array members argv[0] through argv[argc-1] inclusive shall contain pointers to strings, which are given implementation-defined values by the host environment prior to program startup.

Should the word “string” in this context be interpreted as “0-terminated string”, that is, a sequence of non-0 characters followed by a final '\0', or do/may some implementations pass arguments to programs differently?

On a POSIX platform, are the arguments of one of the `exec*` family of functions validated by the `exec*` function as pointers to well-formed strings (and how?), or should a setuid program refrain from assuming that it has been passed well-formed 0-terminated strings as arguments?

Comment: Counter-question: without `\0` termination, how would one reasonably expect to be able to read the strings?

Comment: Well practically, how would you know how long they are otherwise?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Well, if it wasn't for the definition dug up by Oli Charlesworth, a program's argument might have been, on some platform, always up to a maximum of 16 characters.

Comment: The question is essentially asking if a *malicious* (or even simply faulty) program can get exec() to pass on a malformed argument array - that this wouldn't be meaningfully interpretable is irrelevant, since the question concerns *risk* rather than *function*.

Comment: In C, "string" always means "null-terminated string".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Should the word “string” in this context be interpreted as “0-terminated string”, that is, a sequence of non-0 characters followed by a final '\0', or do/may some implementations pass arguments to programs differently?

7.1.1 defines a string:

> A string is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character.

---

> Are the arguments of one of the exec* family of functions validated by the exec* function as pointers to well-formed strings (and how?).

The [POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/exec.html) states that args to the `exec` family are null-terminated strings, and doesn't specify what happens if they aren't.  Presumably it's undefined behaviour.  This seems reasonable, because there's no reasonable way for the `exec` functions to validate that each argument is correctly null-terminated.  (Although bear in mind that `exec*` must copy its arguments, as the address space is about to be swapped out.)

Comment: Okay, the first part of the question is stupid in view of the definition of “string”. How about the second part: on a POSIX platform, can a caller of `exec*` manage to pass a pointer to something other than a well-formed string to use a program argument, and how does `exec*` validate it if it does?

Comment: Without that guarantee, it's not really C, since it's not following the C standard.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: The [POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/exec.html) states that args to the `exec` family are null-terminated strings, and doesn't specify what happens if they aren't.  Presumably it's undefined behaviour (because there's no reasonable way to validate this).

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I am surprised that such a security risk would have been left as “undefined behavior” (but I agree that it is not for the C standard to tell, and perhaps not even for the POSIX one).

Comment: @PascalCuoq: I don't think it can be anything other than UB (how can one check that a string is correctly null-terminated?).  One could argue that each argument should come with an accompanying `length` argument, of course.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Okay, so thinking more about this, if it was for MY operating system, I would define a maximum argument length (4KiB or anything reasonable for the times), and read up to that length from the process calling `execv*`, and if I didn't find a `'\0'` within that limit that would be an error (and/or I would add the terminating 0 to the copy).

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Oh, there **is** such a limit, it's called `ARG_MAX`. Thanks for the link to the relevant standard.

Comment: I should clarify now, if it is not yet clear from my obsession with the point of view of the `exec`ed program, that “undefined behavior in the program calling `exec*`” and “undefined behavior induced in any setuid binary I can put my paws on” are not the same thing and that my question was about the very difference between the two.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: Are you saying that because a malicious "parent" could inject non-terminated "strings" into an `exec`-ed program, the claim of the C standard is incorrect?  I guess the answer is yes, in a sense.  But of course, a malicious OS could do all sorts of things that invalidate the stipulations of the C standard!

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I am interested in a malicious process calling an exec function on a benevolent OS with benevolent setuid binaries, which is not as theoretical.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth & @PascalCuoq, Regardless of what the spec does or doesn't say, as a practical matter  the `exec` call does check for null termination.  Exec has to copy over the arguments to the new process.  On startup the child process' arguments are not pointing to memory allocated in the parent.  This would be unworkable for any pgm that wanted to reference its argv parms after the parent died.  In the process of copy those arguments exec must check for well formed strings otherwise, not sensing null termination(s) it would fail with E2BIG.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Would you mind mentioning in your answer that the strings passed as argument through `argv` to `execve()` are copied before the control is transferred to the new program, and thus that if any of them is ill-formed, execution either does not take place or takes place with a garbage argument that is still a well-formed string? I fear that this information is currently lost in a sea of comments. PS: my question was in the same context as the blog post at http://trust-in-soft.com/finding-vulnerabilities-in-small-challenge-like-c-programs/